# Is mysql_real_escape_string necessary if there are no user inputs?

Tags: php, mysql

Do I have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` for every query or just when there are user inputs on the page?

Let's say I have:

```
$check = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pm='$on'");
    $numrows_check = mysql_num_rows($check);
                if ($numrows_check == 1) {
```

Do I have to worry about SQL injections here if the page has no user inputs?

P.S.
I know `pdo` and `mysqli`, I'm asking specifically for `mysql`. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add that - besides the fact that [mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4577762) - `mysqli` and/or `pdo` still need prepared statements and parameterized queries to [prevent sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4577762).

Comment: Yeah, [you can **NOT** mix APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php) :\ ...

Comment: What you could do is double the work for a transition.. Something like creating a connection with `PDO` and update part by part of the project until you end up with `PDO` only. This is just a thought, I've never done anything like that and if you are really going to, do it at your own risk. Make sure you are able to update a complete part so that it uses only `PDO`. Don't forget to backup your stuff and maybe use some version control... Anyways, best of luck :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL injection can be inject using form and also using links. It means whenever there is input form the user then you have to you **mysq_real_escape_string()**

How injection can inject using link. and example is given below.

```
http:///www.mysite.com?delete.php?id=5
```

if URL like this is shown and some one can change this "5" to his/her desired value. so there are several method to avoid this type of injection a simple solution is that you can use **intval()**.

so it is necessary to use all convention to each and every vulnerable point. so you can be safe form injection. so
       **Prevention is better than cure.**

Comment: so in other words, whenever I have GET_ on a page, I must escape all queries that are associated with it?